# Tranparent Screen over an image Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Can the background of InkPresenter in Silverlight be transparent?

So, whatever I have below the inkPresenter would be visible even after the inkPresenter is open!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to show an image in the area of the InkPresenter you could try giving the InkBrush a [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=VS.95).aspx) as its background.